# Auto generating invoice number

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to automatically generate invoice number using the last invoice number on database table. My sample invoice number is 'INV0000'
Here is what I tried

```
SqlConnection scon1 = new SqlConnection(mycon1);
String myquery1 = "select max(Inv_num) from [dbo].[tblInv_info]";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
cmd1.CommandText = myquery1;
cmd1.Connection = con;
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
da1.SelectCommand = cmd1;
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
da1.Fill(ds1);
txtInvoiceN.Text = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
string a;
a = txtInvoiceN.Text;
a = a  + 1;
txtInvoiceN.Text = a.ToString();
con.Close();
```

The above code works fine but instead of invoice number being INV0001 the output becomes INV00001. I tried to change SQL query to:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(Inv_Num, LEN(Inv_Num)-3))+1) FROM tblInv_info;
```

The output is correct but the first three letters are missing, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you let your database generate the number as a identity column

Comment: Its usually much easier to store a numerical sequence somewhere separate and use that to populate the invoice number. Look up sequences in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot really support what you are trying to do.  If you want an incremental number, then you should use an `identity` column or perhaps a sequence.  Attempting to assign the value this way can lead to problems -- notably, two different threads can produce the same number.

But your question is more about formatting values.  You can do all the manipulation in the database.  Here is one way to produce the number:

```
select concat('INV', format(convert(int, stuff(max(Inv_num), 1, 3, '')) + 1, '0000'))
from [dbo].[tblInv_info]
```

This extracts the maximum number, removes the first three characters, converts to an integer, adds 1 and reformats in your desired way.